# Old sci-fi novel: Deforestation on a distant planet, protagonists have jet packs

Tags: story-identification

Over 40 years ago when I was a child I read a sci-fi book whose first half had been torn off, so I never knew how it began, or its title or author.

All that I still recall from the story is two humans that are colleagues working together on a distant planet doing mass deforestation. They use advanced ground vehicles that cut down the trees with laser beams. One of them gets upset and, in anger, takes out a whole swath of virgin forest. They also have advanced personal jetpacks that they use to survey from the air.

At the end of the book, one of them is so depressed that he takes his jetpack up as high as he can towards the stars above with the purpose of running out of fuel and crashing, thus committing suicide.

Comment: It was an old book, you read it when you were a child? I guess that would have been in the 1940s, then?

Comment: I was reading these in the late 70's but the book was probably older.